# How to run Microsoft access macro from Java

Tags: java, ms-access, macros

We are using Access database for a project along with Java. We have some Macros in Access database and we need to run those from Java. Is there any way to execute those macros from Java?

Comment: I highly doubt that. Java Access libraries are scarce and offer very basic support (mainly reading and writing of data).

Comment: This is quite clearly about programming so I'm not sure why it was closed as off topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works for me in NetBeans 8 on Windows 8.1. It writes a temporary VBScript file and then runs it using cscript.exe:

```java
package runaccessmacro;

import java.io.*;

public class RunAccessMacro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dbFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb";
        String vbsFilePath = System.getenv("TEMP") + "\\javaTempScriptFile.vbs";
        File vbsFile = new File(vbsFilePath);
        PrintWriter pw;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(vbsFile);
            pw.println("Set accessApp = CreateObject(\"Access.Application\")");
            pw.println("accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase \"" + dbFilePath + "\"");
            pw.println("accessApp.DoCmd.RunMacro \"doRidLogUpdate\"");
            pw.println("accessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase");
            pw.println("accessApp.Quit");
            pw.close();

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript /nologo \"" + vbsFilePath + "\"");
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader rdr = 
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            int errorLines = 0;
            String line = rdr.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                errorLines++;
                System.out.println(line);  // display error line(s), if any
                line = rdr.readLine();
            }
            vbsFile.delete();
            if (errorLines == 0) {
                System.out.println("The operation completed successfully.");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Notes:

1. This will only work on a Windows machine with Microsoft Access (the actual application, not just the Access Database Engine) installed.
2. The "bitness" of the JVM under which the Java code runs should match the "bitness" of the version of Access installed (i.e., both 64-bit or both 32-bit).
3. Some tweaking may be required under certain circumstances, e.g., Java code being executed by a web server may be prohibited from shelling out to cscript.exe by default.